# Calling a function from one class in another class

Tags: c++

If I have these two sets of `.cpp` and `.h` files set up like this and I l want to put an `add()` function in `a.cpp` that adds ten integers and returns sum. Then I have class `b` that will return the average but I want to use the sum of the ten integers that I got from class `a`. How can I call function `add()` in function `average()` so it can return the sum? I don't know if this is getting my question across well, I just made this example up to try it illustrate it.

```
class a { 
  private: 
    int a[10];  
  public: 
    a( ); 
    int add( int); 
}; 

class b {
  private:  
    int d; 
  public: 
    int average(int ); 
}
```

Comment: You need an instance of `a` to call the `add()` function, e.g.: `a X; X.add(5);`

Comment: How about adding a function `a::sum()`?

Comment: Having the class name `a` and a member variable `a` is asking for unnecessary confusion. Not sure that is even legal. I suggest changing the member variable to some thing like `data` - `int data[10];`.

Comment: What's about `inheritance`, you can inherit class a on class b, or define `add` function as a `static` method or you may try `composition`, so it depends on your design, but if there's no obvious relation between both classes, I think it's much better to implement add within average function, which also reduces unnecessary function call (`add`).

Comment: What you want to do is not 100% clear to me but it makes me think about "static" class or static members or static class methods... you should check that out. If you don't know what it it is, you should take an Object Oriented Programming class or tutorial before going any further.

Answer (score 0):

You can call member functions on an object of a class, not on the class itself.  Creating an object is almost as creating a variable, for example `a my_a;`.  Then you can use the `add` member function of the `my_a` object as `my_a.add(42)`.

If you do not need objects (but do need classes for some reason), use static member functions and variables as follows.

```
class MyClass {
private:
  static int variable;
public:
  static int accessor() { return variable; }
};
```

In this case, you can call the static member function without creating an instance as `MyClass::accessor()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class A {
   public:
      static int add(int);
};

class B {
   public:
      void average(int val){ 
          A::add(val);
          // Some logic 
      }
};
```

Comment: Hello again, you might want to correct `int average(int a)` in your `b` class to take the correct parameter type. You're trying to call a member function `add()` on a builtin type `int`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace i didn't get your question actually, still its one example to show how to access a member function of a from b's member function.

Comment: No, your `b::average()` member function is taking an `int` parameter called `a`. You're using it as though it was an object of type `a` but it is an `int` (and builtin types don't have member functions). Note, it would be less confusing if your variable names weren't the same as your class names. ...and that same member function has an `int` return type but no `return` statement...

Comment: @Blastfurnace i understand the confusion. I have made some changes, hope its clear now.